# How to Update a table having same id but different data in rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Suppose I have *a table* **t1** having the following data where *id* value doesn't change

| ID | Name | Application_id | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UAT | 123 | USA |
| 1 | TEST | 222 | UK |

Now I want to only update the *name* column of the *1st row only*(below is the desired o/p)

| ID | Name | Application_id | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DEV | 123 | USA |
| 1 | TEST | 222 | UK |

Comment: `update your_table
set name = 'DEV'
where ID = 1 and Applciation_id = 123` ???

Comment: SQL table is a set, it has no inherent order. So there's no "first" row and your question is unclear. Please, define how to identify "first" row in your case.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4489966/how-to-update-a-table-having-same-id-but-different-data-in-rows#latest

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you from using the current value of the column that you are updating. So

```
update <your_table>
   set name = 'DEV' 
 where id = 1 
   and name = 'UAT';
```

Answer (score 0):

*first row* depends on how you sort the data, since the tables represent unordered sets. Presumingly, update your table depending on the ascending sorting of the `application_id` column such as

```sql
MERGE INTO t USING
          (SELECT t.*, 'DEV' AS name_new 
             FROM t
            ORDER BY t.application_id
            FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) t1
          ON ( t1.id = t.id AND t1.application_id = t.application_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.name = name_new
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d81e29830ee14a408e58110807bd815)</kbd>